# How can I get accurate information about disk space used/available in Big Sur via the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, disk-space

### Summary:

I would like to be able to tell how much disk space I have *used* and how much I have *available* (in GB) in Big Sur in a simple format suitable for parsing in a shell script or similar.

### Details

Finder reports that my internal SSD is 995 GB and has 568 GB free.

Simple math tells us that means I have used 427 GB.

#### So… how can I get `568 GB` and/or `427 GB` from the command line?

Hint: **The answer is *not* `df`**

If I do `df -H /` I will get this result (truncated for readability and to just the parts of the output we care about):

```
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity
/dev/disk3s1s1   995G    15G   528G     3%
```

15G *might* be how much the read-only volume takes up, but the “available” amount is off by 40G.

Of course we know that there’s now a separate ‘Data’ volume. So let’s check that using `df -H /System/Volumes/Data`:

```
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity
/dev/disk3s5   995G   445G   528G    46%
```

445G used is *relatively* close to the actual amount of `427G` but if you add up the “Used” (445G) and “Available” (528G) you get 973G.

#### There must be *some* way to do it…

I have noticed that other apps such as iStat Menus and MakeMKV are both able to display accurate information about the remaining disk space. So it’s not as if the system is *incapable* of revealing this information.

If there is another tool besides `df` that can do this, please let me know.

Bonus points if it comes standard with macOS (bash, zsh, python, ruby, whatever), but if it can be installed via `brew` or similar, I’ll take it.

What I’m asking for *seems* very simple, but I can’t figure out how to do it.

p.s. - yes, I’m aware of macOS’ features about “purgeable space” and all that. Not interested. I just want to be able to get the same numbers shown in Finder, iStat Menus, etc. from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

`diskutil info /dev/disk3s1s1` seems to do the trick for me:

```
Container Total Space:     994.7 GB (994662584320 Bytes) (exactly 1942700360 512-Byte-Units)
Container Free Space:      635.1 GB (635058384896 Bytes) (exactly 1240348408 512-Byte-Units)
```

(other output snipped)

My output from `df -H`:

```
/dev/disk3s1s1 995G    15G   634G     3%    568975  9712932825    0%   /
/dev/disk3s5   995G   335G   634G    35%   1363090  9712138710    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
```

Comment: Curious. I get the same (incorrect) information from `diskutil info` that I get from `df`. Does `df` give you the same information as `diskutil info`? Do you use Time Machine? I am wondering if the discrepancy is due to Time Machine snapshots or something like that.

Comment: Edited my df -h output in. I do use Time Machine.

Comment: My Finder shows 994.66 GB total, with 731.04 GB used and 96.88 purgeable, thus 634.16 GB free.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript can get the [free space of a disk](https://help.apple.com/applescript/mac/10.9/#apscrpt182), which gives the same number as the Finder.

Open Script Editor and save the following script as `~/Library/Scripts/Free Space.scpt`:

```
tell the application "Finder"
    -- Change this if your drive is not called "Macintosh HD"
    set drive_name to "Macintosh HD"
    
    set free_bytes to (free space of disk drive_name)
    set free_Gbytes to (free_bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 0.1024) div 100) / 100
    return drive_name & " has " & free_Gbytes & " GB free"
end tell
```

Then run

```
osascript ~/Library/Scripts/Free\ Space.scpt
```

The first time you run it it will popup a dialog asking you if it's OK for osascript to control the Finder.

Note that my AppleScript skills are pretty terrible, so any suggestions on how to improve the above script are welcome.

#### Example output

```
Macintosh HD has 35.85 GB free
```

Comment: The Finder actually shows how many billion (1000000000) bytes are available, not how many (1024^3) bytes are available.
Here's a visually simpler way to do the math.

[ set freeGbytes to (free_bytes div (1000 * 1000 * 10)) / 100 ]

Also, I would encourage putting your return statements outside of tell blocks, for cleaner code nesting.